# How can I config layout to set the first item in ListView has focus in default in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a simple `ListView`, just like this

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

I want to replace `Fragment` with this `ListView`, now I have already implement this, but I want to do more, I want to each time I replace the fragment, **the first item in `ListView` has focus(if the first item exists)**.

How do I config the `ListView` layout file? Now, the config file is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/file_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

------------------------------------------------**update**---------------------------------------------------------------------
Now, I need to press direction `down` to request the first item focus(when the item has focus, the background changed). What I need to do is that the first item has focus when the `ListView` is loaded.

Comment: FragmentManager.replace() can replace a Fragment for you.

You should be able to create another Fragment where the onCreateview() inflates the Layout you posted in your example.

Comment: @crn14 I have already implement this, I just need to make the first item `requestFocus`